# How to search within a product's reviews on Amazon

Tags: search, amazon

When looking at a product's customer reviews on Amazon, there used to be a search box on the right side of the page that allowed you to search for keywords within only that product's reviews. Amazon seems to have removed this feature today -- or did they just move it somewhere else?

Does anyone know the URL for the customer review keyword search results? I'd be curious to see if using the URL will still work, and if I can change the product ID and keywords to search within other products' customer reviews.

(On August 12, 2014, Amazon removed the customer review search box, but on August 13, 2014 they put it back. My answer may still come in handy if they decide to remove it again.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following URL searches for keyword "battery" within the customer reviews for the product with ID B00OQVZDJM.

[https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B00OQVZDJM/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewopt_kywd?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=1&filterByKeyword=battery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OQVZDJM)

Just replace "battery" and "B00OQVZDJM" within the URL to search for a different keyword within a different product's customer reviews.

Comment: Does not work anymore

Comment: Link down...........

Comment: @Pacerier I updated the URL.

Comment: @f01 I updated the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon changed layout a bit. The Search Option still there and got expanded. [image: Amazon Searchable]At the end of the summary for reviews section, click on the blue number that has how many reviews a product has. Then, scroll down to the bottom of the first list of reviews they give you and click "see all (# of reviews)". The search button is on the left.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. In the reviews section, click on the blue number that has how many reviews a product has. Then, scroll down to the bottom of the first list of reviews they give you and click "see all (# of reviews)". The search button is on the left.